# Recommendation: Fast algorithm for logistic random effects?

Tags: r, bayesian, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, c++

What is the fastest algorithm for fitting a simple logistic 'random effects' type model, with only one level of categorical predictors?

Another way of putting it might be a logistic regression with a Gaussian prior on the coefficients, or "with shrinkage".

I'm looking for a very fast and reliable implementation to use in a production environment. This means that the algorithm would need to have a low risk of 'hanging', and a not-drastically-variable time to converge.

There would be between 1 and 5000 data points per 'cell', and 5-100 groups/categories. It would need to exploit sufficient statistics (take counts of group data). Second-level nesting a bonus, but not essential.

This could be done via `lme4` in `R`. However, is there a library (e.g. stand-alone C++) which is more efficient for this narrowly-defined type of model?

EDIT: Goal is inference over prediction - specifically, comparison of group estimates (with standard errors), construction of confidence intervals etc.

EDIT: Just to make it clear, I wouldn't be fitting a 'mixed model' so to speak - there would be no fixed effect. The data would be a very long two-column ('successes', 'failures') contingency table, with highly variable n counts.

EDIT: I need the degree of 'shrinkage' in the individual estimates to be informed by the group level variance (as opposed to banging a Jeffery's prior on each individual estimate, or using an Agresti-Coull (1998) type interval).

Comment: How important is accuracy, ie, how much approximation error are you willing to accept to the likelihood, such as via penalized quasi-likelihood.  See "Efficient Laplacian and Adaptive Gaussian Quadrature Algorithms for Multilevel Generalized Linear Mixed Models" (Piniero and Bates 2006) for discussion.

Comment: Please state your goals, e.g., prediction vs. inference.  If prediction then an empirical Bayes approach through the use of penalized maximum likelihood estimation may be appropriate, and there are some computational speedups available for your special case.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, great to have your input! Question amended.

Comment: @AndrewM, thank you for the reference! My main constraint is performance (ideally <2s runtime), with accuracy superior to banging Wilson intervals on estimates (as per Agresti & Coull, 1998). As standard errors are useful, of the methods in that paper, AGQ2+ would be best. However, my question is really whether my narrow use-case means that there are alternatives to AGQn which may be faster.

Comment: Your most recent edit is intriguing--do you mean that you are just interested in a Binomial probability of success in each group (row of the contingency table) and that you want to regularize this estimate?  In that case, there are empirical-Bayesian things you could do that would have analytic formula.  Perhaps describe the goal of this analysis more fully?

Comment: An analytical solution would be nice and fast! :) To answer your first question, Yes. However, I would like the degree of 'shrinkage' in the individual estimates to be informed by the group level variance (as opposed to banging a Jeffery's prior on each individual estimate, or using an Agresti-Coull type interval). Is there an analytical solution in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Liblinear? It has a fast logistic regression module in c.  There is a modification that allows sample weights http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/ search for sample weights for instances: then you can provide group data counts. (it is used in the  python scikit_learn library without sample weights_ I am working on adding them)

Comment: @gung Expanded answer

Comment: I might be missing something here, but it's not clear to me how logistic regression with sample weights would aid in solving the logistic mixed model.

Comment: @AndrewM - then probably I am missing something. I assumed - "it would need to exploit sufficient statistics (take counts of group data)" - meant that the underlying data is perhaps categorical, so that one does not have to have a row for each instance, but one can aggregate - and so achieve speedups.